# Convert 5 N/mm to mm/N

Tags: arithmetic

My child was asked to convert a number to units in mm/N, from the number $5$ N/mm. How can I swap units from the denominator to the numerator? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Hint: the reciprocal of meters per second, is seconds per meter.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{\text{N}/\text{mm}} = \frac{\text{mm}}{\text{N}}
$$